# Control flow of an IF statement & Asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, structure

My code is structured as follows:

```
IF (something) {
..stuff
..Asynchronous Function Call
}
ELSE (something) {
..stuff
..Asynchronous Function Call
}
..more stuff
```

Let's say the IF condition is met, the code executes 'stuff', then moves onto the Asynchronous Function Call. Will it simple do the call but get out of the IF statement and execute 'more stuff' in the mean time on the assumption of waiting for the Asynchronous Function Call to finish?

OR

Does it finish waiting for the Asynchronous Function Call to finish executing, then continue with 'more stuff' as a normal IF statement block would do.

In the prior case, any advice on how to ensure the Asynchronous Function Call finished before it exits the IF block?

** Note, I've included more stuff inside both Asynchronous Function Calls to ensure the calls are done before it moves on, but I feel this is really bad programming because if I had 50 ELIF's, I would have to copy paste that code 50 times as opposed to just putting it at the end of the IF statement.

Thank you very much for any help provided!

Comment: By the definition of asynchronous, your async function does **NOT** wait for anything else to happen. It finishes executing when it's done, which might be in a millisecond and it might be in 4 hours.

Comment: **Do not edit your post to include self-promotion.** That is in blatant violation of site-wide rules. There is currently a pending edit to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

You can approach this easily and less painfully using JavaScript Promises. Have a look to the following links:

- http://davidwalsh.name/write-javascript-promises
- https://www.promisejs.org/

The basic idea of JavaScript Promises is to the use of asynchronous calls that can be executed in a certain order. Like this:

```
$.when(GET_PRODUCTS).then(
 IF_SUCCESS DO THIS
 ELSE DO THAT
).fail(
 SHOW MESSAGE
 CLEAN EVERYTHING BECAUSE SOMETHING WRONG HAPPENED
).done(
 CLEAN EVERYTHING BECAUSE EVERYTHING WENT OKAY
)
```

With that, you can make code that will be more maintainable. It is not easy to grasp it at the beginning, but give it a try, will save you a lot of headaches!

Answer (score 0):

> Does it finish waiting for the Asynchronous Function Call to finish executing,

No, that isn't what "asynchronous" means. The while point is that it *doesn't* wait. The function will run and finish at some point in the future; the flow of execution continues to the next line immediately.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to your given code, `more stuff` happens while the asynchronous function is happening. It doesn't wait for the asynchronous function to return a result.

Based on your tag of "node.js", I'm assuming your question is about asynchronous calls on the server. However, you can compare the behavior to a client-side AJAX call.

Say you have this:

```
var nav = document.getElementById('nav');

function async(params) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // set up your request

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        // some conditions, and then on success:
        nav.style.color = 'black';
    };

    xhr.open('GET', 'resource.php'+params, true);

    // send your request
}

if ( /* condition */ ) {
    async( /* some parameter */ );
} else {
    nav.style.color = 'red';
}
```

If you were to run the above code, either way, your `#nav` element's color will be set to red at first, but if the async request comes back with a successful response, your `#nav` element's color will be black. This is a very trivial and probably impractical example, but it is one that could be tested pretty easily to confirm that yes, async calls will happen asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

Like others of said you can use Promises, async.js, step.js, etc. To control flow. You can also use generators if you use latest version of node with --harmony enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I **promise** to show you the right way. First off asynchronous if conditions are what you're looking for. Secondly you want a *full* example. You'll have to modify the URL of the AJAX request *and* set some server code to give you responses. I'll provide a *baseline* PHP file towards the end.

So effectively: what if my `if` condition takes too long for the JavaScript parser? JavaScript uses promises. I'm not going to go all-out crazy, my goal here is to provide a baseline. Towards the end of the script you'll notice either success or failure levels. This script requires *two* asynchronous if conditions. Additionally instead of being cheap/static/fragile I've kept the `script` element within the `head` element where it belongs. Lastly ensure you change the HTTP query and acknowledge it at the server, no need to produce redundant files. Browser compatibility is good except no support for IE11 however I've only encountered very specific use-cases to *require* this so if you're considering using this code for non-technical audience I would highly recommend reconsider your initial approach to the given problem.

```
<head>
<script defer="true" type="application/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function request(method,url)
{
 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject)
 {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open(method,url);
  req.withCredentials = true;
  req.onerror = function() {reject(Error('Network error.'));};
  req.onload = function() {if (req.status == 200) {resolve(req.response);} else {reject(Error(new Object({'response':req.response,'status':req.statusText})));}};
  req.send();
 });
}

function aysn_if()
{
 request('get','https://www.example.com/test.php?t=1').then(function(response)
 {
  console.log('Success, level one if!', response);
  request('get','https://www.example.com/test.php?t=2').then(function(response)
  {
  console.log('Success, level two if!', response);
  },
  function(error)
  {
   console.error('Failed, second level.', error);
  });
 },
 function(error)
 {
  console.error('Failed, first level.', error);
 });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (e) {aysn_if();},false);
//]]>
</script>
</head>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '.((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] : '*'));
//JUST for testing, don't send this stuff outside of test environments!
ksort($_SERVER);
print_r($_SERVER);
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You first option is what happens.

You don't have to copy/paste N times. Just put "more stuff" into a function, and pass that function to all your asynchronous callbacks. The callbacks can just call the "more stuff" function when they are done with their normal processing.